# After using pyinstaller to make my program into an exe, selenium stops working

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Basically, as the title says, after I turned my program into an exe it gives me the ModuleNotFoundError and says that I do not have selenium installed. When I try installing selenium with pip it tells me selenium is already installed. Sorry if this is similar to another question, I spent a while trying to find an answer and gave up.

Comment: what were the parameters you have used when you created the exe? put the code you have for python only a few lines where the error is coming will be okay. Add the complete error trace log.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Pycharm is just bad and I messed up my Path and or was using a venv by accident. I had similar errors and reinstalling Pycharm fixed them.